# Forgotten user password for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, password

I recently found my old Lenovo which has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've forgotten my user login. My dad is the registered admin but he's no longer here and I've tried holding the shift key when I restart like so many people have said but nothing notable really happens? 
I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me and explain it as if they're talking to a toddler because computer talk really confuses me.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Boot the LiveCD and mount the root partition of your main system, enter the chroot session and use the passwd command to set the new password. Exit chroot, unmount the root partition and reboot. :)